# How to set {$MYSQL.DSN} macro without creating a odbc.init file in Zabbix server?

Tags: zabbix

How to set `{$MYSQL.DSN}` tamplate macro without creating a `odbc.init` file in Zabbix server?

I've tried something like this, but it does not work

```
"Driver=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc8a.so;Server=192.168.0.10;Port=3306"
```

Is there a way to set `{$MYSQL.DSN}` without creating a `/etc/odbc.init` file in linux server? I don't want to use the data source name.